# How to set SvelteKit stores on the server and retain reactivity?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to build a machine that changes data on the server using a setInterval callback. In an ideal scenario the server checks for data intermittently and saves it in a cache, which the front-end components use present it in the browser. Right now my +server.ts file *says* it's changing data at the interval and adding it to the store, then logs it to the console. But the front-end is not 'seeing' it. I suspect this has to do with context? Here's some code:

stores.js

```
export const colorMachine = writable();
```

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    import { colorMachine } from "$lib/utils/store.js";
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    onMount(async () => {
    
        const machine = await fetch('/api/machine/');
        const newColor = await machine.json();
        colorMachine.set(newColor);
    
    });
</script>
{$colorMachine}
```

/api/machine/+server.ts

```
import { json as json$1 } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { colorMachine } from "$lib/utils/store.js";

let colors = ['red','green','yellow','purple','blue'];

/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export function GET({ params }) {

    startLoop();
    return json$1(colors[0]);

}

function startLoop() {
setInterval(looper, 8000);
}

async function looper () {

    const random = Math.random() * 4;
    const rounded = Math.round(random);
    
    const newColor = colors[rounded];
    
    colorMachine.set(newColor);
    
    let countValue;
    colorMachine.subscribe(value => {
        countValue = value;
    });
    
    console.log(countValue)

}
```

the initial fetch that's sent in onMount isn't the problem, it's the looping function which is supposed to reset that store variable that's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer stores over the network, the code is not referring to the same thing.

You either have to poll the server (sending individual requests in an interval) or create a connection that events/data can be sent through, e.g. via a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) or [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events).

Comment: OK I'll try sending individual requests from the client. Thanks.