# SvelteKit received data from POST route to update client state

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In SvelteKit, I have data that isn't **fetched** but **pushed** instead to the Sveltekit instance from an external service.

I have a basic `routes/update/+server.js` like below. It will be called by an external service with a POST request to http://sveltekithost:5173/update/

```js
// @ts-nocheck
import { error, json } from "@sveltejs/kit";

/** @type {import('../../$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function POST({ request }) {
  try {
    let receivedData = await request.json();
    
    // I want receivedData to somehow be fed through to the page here
    requestDataStore.set(receivedData);  // << this does not pass through to the client
    
  } catch (err) {
    throw error(500, err.message);
  }
  return json({ message: "OK" });
}
```

If I try to save that data to a writeable store, that same store always returns empty on the page.
e.g. NOT WORKING (logs undefined):

```
<script>
   onMount(() => {
     requestDataStore.subscribe((value) => {
       console.log(value);
     });
   });
</script>
```

I guess the question is how do I make a SvelteKit page reactive to an outside source feeding it data?

Comment: Maybe you want to use [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74539913/546730).